# return multiple items in php function

Tags: php

I have this code inside a PHP function:

```
$results = array();
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $results[] = $result;   
        //echo $result["company"].'<br>';
    }
    return $results;
```

then outside of the function, i use:

```
$table = 'customer';
$array = pages($table);
foreach($array as $ret) {
    //display here...
}
```

i want to return some extra HTML code at the end of my function to display a HTML table

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an alternative you could

```
return array("results" => $results, "extra" => $extra);
```

Comment: how do i use this to echo the $extra?

Comment: after using the $results returned in a foreach loop ?

Comment: $value = your_function(); now you can use $value['results'] and $value['extra']

Comment: please note, that this is a quick solution, not the best, see post of lxg

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution: Use [`list()`](http://php.net/list):

```
function returnTwoResults()
{
    $res1 = 'foo';
    $res2 = 'bar';
    return array($res1, $res2);
}

list($foo, $bar) = returnTwoResults();

// $foo is 'foo', $bar is 'bar' now.
```

Quality solution: Work object-oriented and return an object that suits the context.